# Safely remove a drive from eSATA hotswapable enclosure?

Tags: windows-server-2000, hotswap, esata

I have recently installed a Rosewill RSV-S5 eSATA RAID array on a Windows 2000 Server. I'm not using any RAID features - it is configured as 5 discrete drives (JBOD).

The system is based on the Silicon Image Sil3726 and Sil3132R5 chipsets, which support hotswap of SATA drives.

There is no problem inserting a drive into the box while it is running. The drive is recognized an comes online as expected, just like a USB drive would. 
My question is how to "safely" remove the drive. The drives in the RSV-S5 do not appear in the "Safely Remove Hardware" list where USB drives appear.

How can I safely unmount and remove a drive without shutting down the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897438.aspx

Use this prog to flush the write cache and then it should be safe to remove it.

(assuming that your sata controller and drivers support hotswap)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I tried running "SYNC -r I:" and I still got the "Unsafe Removal" dialog after removing the drive. The Show Unplug/Eject icon on the taskbar" checkbox is checked, but the drive is not included in the list of removable drives.

Answer (score 0):

I just purchased a license of safelyremove. It works with sata controllers too not only with usb. It's very nice. There is a full trial on the website http://www.safelyremove.com